# Chart content not getting loaded in popup

Tags: javascript, leaflet, chart.js

I'm trying to get a leaflet popup to display a Chart.js doughnut, but cant get it to work. I have the popup firing but the chart content wont load.

```
onEachFeature: function(feature, layer) {
    var chartData = [{
        value: 200,
        color:"#F7464A",
        highlight: "#FF5A5E",
        label: "Size"
    }, {
        value: 100,
        color: "#46BFBD",
        highlight: "#5AD3D1",
        label: "Value"
    }]

    L.DomUtil.create('canvas', 'popupGraph');
    var ctx = document.getElementById("popupChart").getContext("2d");
    var chartOptions = {
        animation: false
    };

    new Chart(ctx).Doughnut(chartData, chartOptions);

    var content = "<canvas id='popupChart'></canvas>;
    layer.bindPopup(content)
```

Comment: Quotes missing in the line "var content = "<canvas id='popupChart'></canvas>;"

Comment: I have edited the title to explain your actual problem. It is better to use a title that captures your problem instead of just specifying the languages/libraries used. Please edit in the specific error message that you're getting in the console because that information is generally important for debugging.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to make a few changes to get it to work.

> L.DomUtil.create('canvas', 'popupGraph');

You are creating a canvas element with *class* popupGraph, but you don't append it to the DOM structure (i.e. there is no container). I don't see it used in the code sample too.

---

> var ctx = document.getElementById("popupChart").getContext("2d");

At *this point*, I don't think you have an element with ID = popupChart added (you seem to be adding code *to add it* down the line). So, unless your HTML already has an element with ID = popupChart, this is not going to work.

---

> new Chart(ctx).Doughnut(chartData, chartOptions);
>
> ...
>
> layer.bindPopup(content)

You should draw the chart only once the canvas element is visible (otherwise Chart.js will assume the width and height is 0) and properly sized. You need to move this to *after* you have your canvas element added and visible.

The HTML (i.e. the canvas element) will be shown only once your popup is visible, which in turn will happen only after you click on the layer. Only after the popup is open should you do a new Chart(ctx)...

Comment: Of course, there is also the missing quote as pointed out by Monie corleone